# Define cipher suite for TLS in JCA

Tags: java, cryptography, ssl, jca

I want the support of the following cipher suites in TLS using JCA:

- TLS_PSK_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
- TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
- TLS_PSK_WITH_NULL_SHA
- TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
- TLS_PSK_WITH_NULL_SHA256

They are available in [JDK7](http://download.java.net/jdk7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html) but not [JDK6](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html), neither BouncyCastle.

If I want the support in JDK6, could I extends JCA to implement the support of these PSK extensions, using SPI, providers and callback methods of JSSE. I can already redefine or add new cipher implementations on runtime, but I'm not sure JCA offers enough granularity to add new cipher suites in TLS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clean way would be to implement your own [SSLSocketFactory](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html).

If you want to try adding I only see the way to modify the internal classes via reflection.

The relevant class is:

`com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.CipherSuite`

It has an overloaded private static method "add" for adding cipher implementations to the supported list. May be worth a try.

Answer (score 3):

Still not sure it is possible or not, but we found [an implementation of several TLS PSK cipher suites](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jessie-psk-tls/) for the Jessie Library.