# Python paho-mqtt Connect to MQTT broker

Tags: python, mqtt, mosquitto, messagebroker

I'm using this python script to implement a Paho(MQTT) subscriber but i am unable get any responce messages.i am able to subscribe mqtt brokerin command prompt by using `mosquitto_sub -t "" -d -h -p 8883 --psk foo --psk-identity bar --insecure --tls-version tlsv1`

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))

    # Subscribing in on_connect() means that if we lose the connection and
    # reconnect then subscriptions will be renewed.
    client.subscribe("*********")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect("*********", 8883, 60)

client.loop_forever()
```

When I run above python script then it does not respond any error or message but keep going with loop , I also run it line by line and when I run `client.connect("*********", 8883, 60)` then it shows only **0** . please note here without psk and psk-identity we cannot connect to broker.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that the Python Paho client supports PSK TLS connections

Comment: Thanks, what are the options with PSK TLS support?

Comment: Have you actually configure the broker with PSK TLS? Why can't you use normal TLS certs and Username/password or client certificates to identify the clients?

Comment: Mqtt broker is configured in other coutry and we need to connect with its topic , they provided us mqtt fqdn , psk , psk-identity , topic

Comment: @OwaisAjaz You can use tls_set() function for configuring tls related options for more info on function check : https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/

Comment: @OwaisAjaz This answer has an example of how to do it with the Java Paho client https://stackoverflow.com/a/49431225/504554

Comment: @Ashish that doesn't let you set up TLS_PSK only set the certs

Comment: What if we ask our project client to give us tls certs , username and password as mentioned by @hardillb ??

Comment: Then you follow the doc on how to connect with TLS and username and certs

Answer (score 0):

Please check with your topic carefully, sometimes missing of / or # cause this problem.

or

Try This

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
   print("Message Recieved from broker: " + msg.payload.decode())
```